# Unable to mock a value from an imported module in pytest

Tags: pytest

I have the following project setup

```
configs.py
tests/
   test_a.py
```

Inside configs.py, I have a variable:

```
abc = 'Old value'
```

Inside test_a.py, I have a test like this:

```
from configs import abc
import pytest
from unittest import mock

def test_a():
    with mock.patch('configs.abc', 'New value'):
        assert abc == 'New value'
```

For some reason, the value does not gets mocked. It stays equal to 'Old value'. Why is this happening ?

Comment: I am using pytest version pytest==7.1.3

Answer (score 0):

You're failing to reference the newly patched variable.

You can do so by utilizing the `as` keyword

```
with mock.patch('configs.abc', 'New value') as mock_abc:
        assert mock_abc == 'New value'
```

Or even by re-importing the module

```
with mock.patch('configs.abc', 'New value'):
        from configs import abc
        assert abc == 'New value'
```